# Mujoco sim.step() function is not showing new observations

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, robotics, mujoco

I have this code in python which works.

```
sim.reset()
sim.step()
print(sim.data.qpos)
print(sim.data.get_body_xpos("EE"))

print()
sim.data.ctrl[:] = [-0.244,-0.66,-0.785,-1.79,2.42,-0.126]
sim.step()
print(sim.get_state())
print(sim.data.get_body_xpos("EE"))

print()
sim.data.qpos[:] = [-0.244,-0.66,-0.785,-1.79,2.42,-0.126]
sim.forward()
sim.step()
print(sim.data.qpos)
print(sim.data.get_body_xpos("EE"))
```

Clearly, this is not in a loop, and I get the expected out from each print statement. However, for reinforcement learning, thigs need to be in a loop., so I have this simplied code

```
EPOCHS = 5000
STEPS = 100000
TARGET_POS = [-0.47367866, 0.01074746, 0.76153706]


for i in range(EPOCHS):
    done = 0
    sim.reset()
    sim.forward()
    sim.step()
    observation = sim.data.get_body_xpos("EE")
    distance = 0
    iterator = 0
    while not done:
        action = agent.select_action(observation)
        sim.data.ctrl[:] = action
        sim.forward()
        sim.step() #required to update the joints and EE

        new_observation = sim.data.get_body_xpos("EE")
      
        print(iterator, observation)
        print(iterator, new_observation)
     
        reward = ur5_reward_func(new_observation, TARGET_POS)
        distance += reward

        iterator+=1

        done = check_in_target_sphere(TARGET_POS,new_observation) #function returns a 1 if the EE coordinates are in the sphere, else 0
        
        agent.replay_buffer.append(observation, action, reward, done, new_observation, iterator)

        if( agent.replay_buffer.get_buffer_size() > agent.REPLAY_BATCH_SIZE ):
            agent.update_parameters()
        
        

        observation = new_observation

        if(done == True):
            break
```

If you pay attention to the print statement in the loop, for the observation and new_observation, they are the same value which should not be happening. Is there something I am doing wrong? I am certain that the action taken has different values; therefore both observations should be different. Both observations have the same values in a given time step, for the next time step, they will have the same different numbers. See below for some data.

```
0 [-1.91900000e-01 -3.16096174e-08  1.00110000e+00]
0 [-1.91900000e-01 -3.16096174e-08  1.00110000e+00]
1 [-1.91900000e-01 -1.07517997e-06  1.00110000e+00]
1 [-1.91900000e-01 -1.07517997e-06  1.00110000e+00]
2 [-1.91900000e-01 -3.06696987e-06  1.00110000e+00]
2 [-1.91900000e-01 -3.06696987e-06  1.00110000e+00]
3 [-1.91900000e-01 -6.54398293e-06  1.00110000e+00]
3 [-1.91900000e-01 -6.54398293e-06  1.00110000e+00]
4 [-1.91900000e-01 -1.11859614e-05  1.00110000e+00]
4 [-1.91900000e-01 -1.11859614e-05  1.00110000e+00]
```

Again, I am certain that the action being taken is different.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who goes throw this hell...

The .step() function modifies the variable that you assign sim.data.get_body_xpos("EE") to. Therefore, you need to use a copy function like so sim.data.get_body_xpos("EE").copy() so that the .step() function do not directly bind to the variable that's getting the "EE" coordinates.

Also you may want to use qpos instead of ctrl, depending on what you're doing.

Kind regads